# Plotting 3d plot in python

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a 3d plot in Python but not able to do as required.

I am using each value of d and then for each value d I have 4 values of f_sample for which I am calculating FSPL. Later appending values in a single array

I want to plot d, f_sample, and FSPL_remotes in a same 3d plot. Since d and f_sample have same dimension which is 4 but FSPL_remotes has 16 (since each value of d has 4 values of f_sample and there are 4 f_sample)
I am unable to plot it.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
d =[23.1476,125.4207,146.0814,129.8549]
f_sample = [902,904,906,908]
FSPL_remotes = []

for i in d:
        for j in f_sample:
            FSPL = 32.44 + 20*math.log10(i) +20*math.log10(j)
            FSPL_remotes.append(FSPL)
```

Answer (score 1):

just adding some boilerplate from [matplotlib 3d surface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)

```py
import math
d =[23.1476,125.4207,146.0814,129.8549]
f_sample = [902,904,906,908]
FSPL_remotes = []

for i in d:
    for j in f_sample:
        FSPL = 32.44 + 20*math.log10(i) +20*math.log10(j)
        FSPL_remotes.append(FSPL)
        
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
(x,y) = np.meshgrid(d,f_sample)
z = np.array(FSPL_remotes).reshape(4,4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})


# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

Edit: for wireframe:

```
surf = ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

for scatterplot

```
surf = ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed, for that prompt response. How should go for a line plot instead of a surface plot? The surface plot is kind of covering the trend of how the points are changing, and I am unable to read them. Also, how would you annotate all the points that are being plotted?

Comment: @KetanShende you should take a look at [matplotlib 3d plots docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/index.html) ... i think you are looking for a [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-scatter3d-py) or [wireframe plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-wire3d-py), with [text annotations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/text3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-text3d-py)